# How to call "click" event and animation on element simultaneosly in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have four div elements on my html page. I need them to start moving on page load. I need first div to change size WHILE MOVING when user click on it. Div elements must start moving on page load, and first div must change size when user click on it. I dont know how to combine ongoing animation with click event. Here is code:

```
HTML
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Animation</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="id_1" style="background:purple; width:100px; height:100px; border-radius:50%; position:absolute; z-index:1000;"></div>

    <div id="id_2" style="background:blue; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute;"></div>

    <div id="id_3" style="background:yellow; width:300px; height:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

    <div id="id_4" style="background:green; width:300px; height:100px; border-radius:50%;position:relative; float:right;"></div>

</body>
<script src="script2.js"></script>

</html>

jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#id_1").animate({left:700, top: 500}, 10000).animate({left:0},10000).animate({top:0},10000);


$("#id_2").animate({left:800}, 10000).animate({top:400},10000).animate({left:0},10000).animate({top:0},10000);

$("#id_3").animate({top: 500}, 10000).animate({left:400},10000).animate({left:0, top:0},10000);

$("#id_4").animate({top: 500, right: 500}, 10000).animate({top:700},2000).animate({right:800},2000).animate({top:0, right:0},10000);
});`enter code here`

$("#id_1").click(function(){

    $("#id_1").animate({

        "width":"500px",

        "height":"500px"

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the click function inside document ready.

```js
jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {

$.fn.divOneAnimations = function() {
    this.animate({
        left: 700,
        top: 500
    }, 10000).animate({
        left: 0
    }, 10000).animate({
        top: 0
    }, 10000);
};

$("#id_1").on('click', function() {
    $("#id_1").animate({
        height: 500,
        width: 500
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
    });
}).divOneAnimations();

/*
  $("#id_1").animate({
    left: 700,
    top: 500
  }, 10000).animate({
    left: 0
  }, 10000).animate({
    top: 0
  }, 10000);

  $("#id_1").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({
      width: "500px",
      height: "500px"
    }, 2500);
  });
*/


  $("#id_2").animate({
    left: 800
  }, 10000).animate({
    top: 400
  }, 10000).animate({
    left: 0
  }, 10000).animate({
    top: 0
  }, 10000);

  $("#id_3").animate({
    top: 500
  }, 10000).animate({
    left: 400
  }, 10000).animate({
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  }, 10000);

  $("#id_4").animate({
    top: 500,
    right: 500
  }, 10000).animate({
    top: 700
  }, 2000).animate({
    right: 800
  }, 2000).animate({
    top: 0,
    right: 0
  }, 10000);
});
`enter code here`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_1" style="background:purple; width:100px; height:100px; border-radius:50%; position:absolute; z-index:1000;">First Div</div>

<div id="id_2" style="background:blue; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute;"></div>

<div id="id_3" style="background:yellow; width:300px; height:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

<div id="id_4" style="background:green; width:300px; height:100px; border-radius:50%;position:relative; float:right;"></div>
```

Comment: I managed to do it with $("#id_1").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({
      width: "500px",
      height: "500px"
    }, 2500);
  }); but can it be done with animate in some way not CSS